# GPU Tensorflow Installation issue

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I am a new user of Ubuntu, and was spending the last whole week trying to get `gpu tensorflow` to work. But whenever I tried to import `tensorflow`, I received this:

```
import tensorflow
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5.1.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA   library libcuda.so.1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH:   :/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: ___
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: Permission denied: could not open driver version path for reading: /proc/driver/nvidia/version
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1091]  LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1092] failed to find libcuda.so on this system: Failed precondition: could not dlopen DSO: libcuda.so.1; dlerror: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.367.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
```

In the folder I only found `libcuda.so` but not `libcuda.so.1`

Comment: Please check my answer here! https://askubuntu.com/a/1074017/824055 Cheers!